# SQL Server : cannot execute sp_enable_sql_debug

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been using SQL Server Management Studio for over a year on my computer and today I login to my database like usual and I run a query and an error appears:

> The execute permission was denied on the object 'sp_enable_sql_debug', database 'msmsqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'. Error:29

Upon google everyone says to grant permission to that stored procedure like:

```
GRANT Execute on sys.dbo.sp_enable_sql_debug to 'ME'
```

the `ME` is my database login

When I run that `GRANT` statement, I get the same error message. Seems like I cannot grant the permissions?

Can anyone help here?

Comment: You need to be a member of the sysadmin role in order to execute that proc. Is this a local SQL Server, or a remote one? In case of the latter, I suspect someone removed your sysadmin priviledges, and that's why you're seeing the error now.

Comment: This is a local SQL Server on my laptop.  How can I reinstate the sysadmin privledges without running that grant script that returns and error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no dbo in the grant statement. You will have to add the user to master for the grant to work.

Answer (score 0):

They should already be a member of master. You're granting explicit right for a named user.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).